# QML ListView - change all but current item

Tags: qt, listview, model, qml, qtquick2

I'm following [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-declarative-modelviews-listview-expandingdelegates-example.html) tutorial (without the flickable content in each entry) for Qt **4.8** while using Qt **5.7** with `QtQuick 2.0`. The way the `ListView` there works is as follows:

1. User clicks on item in list
2. Alternative (detailed) view of item is displayed
3. User has to click on `Close` button in detailed view to reset the state of entry to its default compact view.

This leads to a clutter where at some point if the user clicks on all items in which case all will be shown in their full view. Having the user click on the `Close` button every time he/she opens a detailed view also is (omho) not that handy.

I've altered the entry to close when the user clicks on the view. I'm also trying to prevent this clutter and achieve a more (omho) flowing behaviour:

1. User clicks on item in list
2. Alternative view of item is displayed
3. User clicks on detailed view to reset state of entry to its default compact view **OR**
4. User clicks on another entry and all currently in detailed view entries are reset to their compact view

Currently I'm looping through my `ListView`'s `contentItem.children[loop_index]` and setting the state to `""` (`"Details"` = show detailed view | `""` = show compact view). Due to the way `ListView` works (loading/unloading delegates on demand) this is quite unreliable and I often get an undefined reference when I try to access the state of other delegates. The following `MouseArea`, which I'm using to do all that, is part of every delegate:

```
// state is a QML `State` that is bound to the delegate (see below for the details on it)
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: background
    onClicked: {
        // Iterate through all other entries and close them
        for (var entry = 0; entry < listView.count; ++entry) {
            if(listView.contentItem.children[entry] !== gestureEntry) {
                console.log("Hide other element");
                listView.contentItem.children[entry].state = ""; // IT FAILS HERE (SOMETIMES)
            }
        }

        // Change view of current entry
        if(gestureEntry.state === "Details") {
            gestureEntry.state = "";
            console.log("Hiding details")
        }
        else {
            gestureEntry.state = "Details";
            console.log("Showing details");
        }
    }
}
```

with `state` being a delegate's state:

```
states: State {
    name: "Details"

    PropertyChanges { target: background; color: "white" }
    PropertyChanges { target: gestureImage; width: 130; height: 130 } // Make picture bigger
    PropertyChanges { target: gestureEntry; detailsOpacity: 1; x: 0; y: 0 } // Make details visible
    PropertyChanges { target: gestureEntry; height: listView.height } // Fill the entire list area with the detailed view
}
```

I'm thinking that the `state` information can be stored inside the `ListModel` itself making it possible to iterate through the model's contents (which are always there unlike the contents of the delegates) however I don't know how to automatically update my list (and the currently visible/invisible delegates) when an entry changes in the model. From what I've found so far it seems not possible to do that since the `ListView` doesn't actively monitor its `ListModel`.

Is this indeed the case? If yes, then is it possible to go around this problem in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `currentIndex` property of your `ListView`?
Just modify your delegate like this:

```
Item {
    id: gestureEntry
    ...
    state: ListView.isCurrentItem?"Details":""
    ...
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: background
        onClicked: {
            if(listView.currentIndex == index)
                listView.currentIndex = -1
            else
                listView.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The only issue with the solution above is that - upon loading - an entry in the `ListView` is preselected which automatically triggers the detailed view of that entry. In order to avoid that the following needs to be added to `listView`:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    listView.currentIndex = -1;
}
```

This ensures that no entry will be preselected.

Comment: Ah, wait. Now the closing upon click on the entry doesn't work... XD I actually do need the `if-else` inside `onClicked`. This breaks your solution though. :-/

Comment: Edited my answer. Hopefully this will work this time :)

Comment: The only problem remaining is that the first time the `ListView` is loaded the first entry (I guess the one that is preselected upon loading of the list) is in detailed view.

Comment: Fixed it. Added `Component.onCompleted: { listView.currentIndex = -1; }` to avoid preselecting an entry.

Answer (score 2):

guess it is an issue because you stored a state in your delegate. You should not do this as described in the `delegate`-property ([Link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop)), because the delegates get reused when they get out of view.

At least you should use a `when: ListView.isCurrentItem` in the State and depend on a value of the ListView. So only your current delegate is maximized. Then in the MouseArea only set `ListView.view.currentIndex = index'. **Don't** change the state manually in the function!

I ran in the same trouble, removed the states completely and just used the attached property `ListView.isCurrentItem`. But binding the state to a Value from the ListView should also work, because it's not stored in the delegate.

Minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 3
        spacing: 5
        currentIndex: -1
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: delegate
            color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "lightblue" : "green" // directly change properties depending on isCurrentItem
            height: 100
            width: 100

            states: State {
                name: "maximized"
                when: delegate.ListView.isCurrentItem // bind to isCurrentItem to set the state
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: delegate
                    height: 200
                }
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                //onClicked: delegate.ListView.view.currentIndex = model.index // if only selection is wanted
                onClicked: {
                    //console.debug("click");
                    if (delegate.ListView.isCurrentItem)
                    {
                        delegate.ListView.view.currentIndex = -1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        delegate.ListView.view.currentIndex = model.index;
                    }
                }
            }
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
            }
        }
        Text {
            text: "CurrentIndex: " + parent.currentIndex
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError` at `ListView.view.currentIndex = index;`

Comment: I've also tried changing it to `listView.view.currentIndex = index;` (since my `ListView` has that ID but the problem is still present.

Comment: The ListView gets attatched to your delegate-root-item, as index is. Maybe you have to explicitly use `delegateId.ListView.currentIndex = delegateId.index`. or even invoke a signal in the delegate there it should work. I've used it a lot and it definately works here, using Qt 5.5.1.

Comment: The `gestureEntry` is the `Item` inside the `gestureDelegate` which is the `Component` used in the `delegate` of my `ListView`.

Comment: Similar problems occur like with the solution of @Yoann: first item is opened in detailed view upon loading of the `ListView` the first time along with the issue that the user is not able to change back to compact view upon clicking on the selected entry.

Comment: I already did that with the other answer. :P Thanks for the effort though. +1